# How can we pass the value from directive to directive template and use that in another directive scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I tried to pass the directive attribute value to template id and that can be used in another directive

**Here is my index.html**

```
<my-value name="jhon"></my-value>
```

**Here is my js code**

```
.directive('myValue',function(){
  return {
    restrict:"E",
    templateUrl:"myname.html",
    scope: {
      name:"="
    },
    link:function(scope,element,attr) {
    }
  }
});
```

**here is my myname.html**

```
<div>
<p  slide heading="name"></p>
</div>
```

In this above code **"slide"** is another directive

**here is slide Directive code**

```
.directive('slide',function(){
  return{
    restrict:"A",
    link:function(scope,elem,attr){
      console.log(attr.heading);
      // Here i want the name first i assigned in index.html as like    "attr.heading = jhon"
    }
  }
})
```

my problem is i assigned `name="jhon"` to my-value directive i want to send that name dynamically to my-value directive template and from there i have to assign that name to slide directive attribute `heading= name` and that have to use in slide directive link because i want to pass the name dynamically from one directive to that directive template and from there i have to assign to another directive attribute and that name have to use in slide directive link function

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which type of control are you trying to make?

Comment: have to pass the name "jhon" dynamically from my-value directive  to slide directive attribute. @Pushpendra

Comment: just stick it to $root-scope and use name value from there in both directive?

Comment: And for the moment what `console.log(attr.heading);` gave you ? It that simply `name` that you have ?

Comment: i want the "jhon" as a result when i print attr.heading in console, but the result i got is "name", in myname.html i want to assign "jhon" to heading attribute @e666

Comment: So you have the answer now ;-)

Comment: no i didn't got the answer, waht iam asking is how ca i assign "jhon" to heading attribute and how ca i use that heading attribute in another directive i.e, in  slide directive @e666

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
        var app = angular.module("my-app",[]);

        app.directive('myValue',function(){
            return {
                restrict:"E",
                template:'<div><p  slide heading="{{name}}"</p></div>',
                scope: {
                    name:"="
                },
                link:function(scope,element,attr) {
                }
            }
        });

        app.directive('slide',function(){
            return{
                restrict:"A",
                link:function(scope,elem,attr){
                    console.log(attr.heading);
                    // Here i want the name first i assigned in index.html as like    "attr.heading = jhon"
                }
            }
        })

        app.controller('demoCtrl',['$scope',function($scope) {

          $scope.myname = "john"
        }]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="my-app">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    
</head>
<body>
   <div ng-controller="demoCtrl">

       <my-value name="myname"></my-value>
   </div>

</body>
</html>
```

just change the below lines.

myname.html

```
<div>
<p  slide heading="{{name}}"></p>
</div>
```

index.html

```
 <my-value name="myname"></my-value>
```

here asign some controller variable instead of static name "john" for two way data binding to work. e.g

```
app.controller("...",function($scope){
$scope.myname = "john"
})
```

Comment: what you have said is right but when used attr.heading in slide directive "jhon" have to print in console.log()

Comment: And what it is printing now ? It seems to be good with that solution.

Comment: it is printing as "name" only not as jhon @e666

Comment: it is printing john , please make sure you done all the changes

Comment: check above code snippet , it will print john in console. @Midhunsai

Comment: here is my plunkr just verify this here the result is not coming http://plnkr.co/edit/Qcx2BdnoPfuy9V8P2qAv?p=preview @DineshShah

Comment: there is some error in your plunkr ,
 1 ) you are passing static name "midhun" instead of controller varible txt.
 2 ) you are not using isolated scope (in plunkr code ), so you dont need to pass  my-name , u can directly access txt in directive as scope.txt , because u can acces  the parent scope @Midhunsai

Comment: now i used your code and corrected the code as like you mentioned, the only thing is you used link function in slide directive but iam using compile in slide directive when i use compile function in slide directive I updated the pulknr see this @DineshShah http://plnkr.co/edit/Qcx2BdnoPfuy9V8P2qAv?p=preview